# Application of DOS Penalty vs. Definition of Victory in DOS

Tags: dos

In the card game DOS, the sequel to UNO, there is a rule stating:

> **Going Out**
> If you ever have EXACTLY TWO CARDS in your hand, you must shout out "DOS!" (meaning "two"). If you forget to do so and another player calls out "DOS!" before you do, you must immediately draw two cards as a penalty. If this happens during your turn, do not add the penalty cards to your hand until the end of your turn.

There is another relevant rule:

> **Ending the Round**
> The round ends when one player goes out by getting rid of all the cards in his of her hand. That player earns points for the cards left in the other players' hands
> (NOTE: *If the player earned any Double Color Match Bonuses on the turn they went out, remember to have the other players draw cards before scoring*).

***If I forget to say "DOS!" and I'm caught by an opponent during my turn, I do not add the cards to my hand until the end of my turn.***

**If I then play all of my cards on that same turn, what happens?**

1. Do I end my turn and take the two cards?
   (And I must then also immediately say "DOS!" at risk of additional penalty)?

Or

2. Have I won the game?
   (the rule never specifies that I must have gotten rid of the cards
   after the **end of my turn**, so at one point I had zero cards)?

Comment: Do the rules allow playing more than 1 card on the same turn?

Comment: Yes, the action taken is completely legal.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [DOS rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/FRM36-DOS.pdf):

You should take the two penalty cards at

> the end of your turn.

**not after** the end of your turn.

This means that you now have two cards left and must immediately say "DOS!".

[Official DOS Rules by Mattel](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/FRM36-Eng.pdf)

Comment: Good point, but my question is more about whether I ever had zero cards in my hand. Since by rule penalty cards should not enter my hand until *the end of my turn*, the point is that if I play all my cards *before the end of my turn* but was also caught not saying "DOS", aren't those penalty cards considered "not in my hand" for the purpose of winning the game?

Comment: Because the rule says not to add them to my hand until *the end of my turn*, and it also says I win when I get rid of all cards in my hand; the timing would suggest that the penalty cards aren't "in my hand" yet when I play all the other cards (it's not the end of my turn yet) and therefore win the game before they resolve.

Comment: No you don't win, you can not win until then end of your turn and then you don't have zero cards in your hand...

Comment: "You cannot win until the end of your turn" *This* is what I can't find any evidence to support.